# i want to show four random numbers minimum one maximum ten but contains one number fix

Tags: android

I want to show 4 options of numbers as like quiz options, out of four three should be wrong and one should be the right answer. All options are numeric numbers, and I want to change right answer's position every time when page opens. Please help me

and my result is in a String result, where i will add result.....

I'm trying this , but not getting the solution

```
LinearLayout rowoptions = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] s = new String[4];
while (numbers.size() < 4) {
    int random = r.nextInt(10)+1;
    int chk = r.nextInt(4)+1;
    if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
        numbers.add(random);
        s[chk] =String.valueOf(random);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Button optionbutton = new Button(this);
    optionbutton.setText(s[i]);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
    layoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
    optionbutton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    //ivBowl.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    rowoptions.addView(optionbutton);
}
```

Comment: is this your requirement that you want to show four random  number buttons and one among them is answer but I would like to know Where is your answer..?

Comment: @Pragnani your are right , i am trying to add my answer but i do not understand where i will add my answer , my answer is into a String result

Comment: While you have example code (great!), but you have not clearly stated your inputs and expected outputs. Having more detailed example would be very helpful to understand what your challenge is. For example, I would encode input answers as 1,2,3,4 (where 1 is always correct answer), then randomize this sequence on output to have something like 3,4,1,2.

Comment: i want to add options at top of buttons , but the right answer's problem will be change when page reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi do you need something like this

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    list.add(answer);
    Random r=new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int next=r.nextInt(10)+1;
            if(!list.contains(next))
            {
            list.add(next);
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        final Button b=new Button(this);
        b.setText(list.get(i).toString());

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedAnser=Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());
                if(!(selectedAnser==answer))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        layout.addView(b);
    }
```